# How can I pass this custom class to new view controller

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a navigation controller that is displaying a certain view controller. I also have a custom class (in another file) of type image view to style all of a user's friends to display on the view controller. The custom image view is userInteractionEnabled with a tap gesture recognizer so that when the user taps on an imageView, the friend's username is printed to the console.

I'm trying to figure out how I can send whichever imageView was tapped to a new viewController

The custom imageView's are instantiated in a for loop depending on how many friends a user has.

Inside the custom image view class file:

```
func iconTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("icon number \(self.tag) tapped")
    print("username: \(self.username)")

    ***somehow need to send this icon back to the view controller 
        so I can push a new one onto the navigation controller with this data***

}
```

Comment: How about you add a custom init to your viewController? or add properties to the viewController you want to push and set them before pushing?

Comment: Add a property in your custom Image view class that has a reference to the viewcontroller `var presentingVC : YourViewContorllerClass`. Also define a property on the viewcontroller that stores the tapped image view `var tappedImageView : UIImageView`. When an icon  tapped set `presentingVC.tappedImagView = Which ever image was tapped`

Comment: @TheAppMentor I was thinking along these lines, but I don't see how that data is sent/ how I can perform segue since the iconWasTapped function is inside the custom image view class

Comment: @ZonilyJame can you expand? i don't see your train of thought with the custom init. The number of image views will always be dynamic and i'm trying to send the specific one that was tapped to the next view controller

Comment: @ZonilyJame on second thought, I see what you mean now, but i still don't see how the data is passed even to the new view controller...The iconTapped function is in the custom IV file so how does that data get passed to the custom init when the segue code will be in the current view controller?

Comment: `let vc = SomeViewController(); vc.someProperty = someValue; self.presentViewController(vc);` the data is now passed since you've passed someProperty to `vc`

Comment: @ZonilyJame the custom class is an image view so it does not have a presentViewController method

Comment: @user7804097 but didn't you say you wanted to pass a custom class to a new viewController?

Comment: the `someProperty` could just be a `variable` of type `someCustomClass` inside your other `ViewController`